# What does 16#00 mean?

Tags: erlang

Looking at the code in this [erlang file](https://github.com/zeromq/ezmq/blob/master/src/ezmq_frame.erl) there is a function like this:

```
socket_type_atom(16#00) ->      pair;
socket_type_atom(16#01) ->      pub;
socket_type_atom(16#02) ->      sub;
socket_type_atom(16#03) ->      req;
socket_type_atom(16#04) ->      rep;
socket_type_atom(16#05) ->      dealer;
socket_type_atom(16#06) ->      router;
socket_type_atom(16#07) ->      pull;
socket_type_atom(16#08) ->      push.
```

From what I understand of erlang integer notation, 5#10 means integer 5 in base ten. So what does the `16#00` stand for?

Comment: 0 in base 16, i.e. 0x0  ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As described in [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html):

> There are two types of numeric literals, integers and floats. Besides
>   the conventional notation, there are two Erlang-specific notations:
>
> ```
> $char
> ASCII value or unicode code-point of the character char.
>
> base#value
> Integer with the base base, that must be an integer in the range 2..36.
> In Erlang 5.2/OTP R9B and earlier versions, the allowed range is 2..16.
> ```

So, the `16#number` is just `number` in hexadecimal. For example:

```
1> 16#10 == 16.
true
```

or binary:

```
2> 2#11111111.
255
```